# Connection error 10060 while connect to apple push service

Tags: php, windows, sockets, stream-socket-client

im using windows server and run php 5

i got this error

```
Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. ) in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\..domain..\simplepush.php on line 21
Failed to connect: 10060 A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

i abort the firewall on the server to be sure its not port issue..

the source file is

```
<?php

// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = '0b98f290f8b0ba40f1d476f7196b5195f5c61299cd536bdc429ea3e397ab5259';

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'Test123';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'My first push notification!';

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

another thing, when i run this script on mac its succeeded without abny trouble.

any one know how to fix it?
or at least what the problem is?

thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

You need to be running the service on a hosting setup with ssl enabled, if on a Windows machine use WAMP with PHP extension OpenSSL enabled (you can enable it by clicking the system tray icon for WAMP and choosing openssl from PHP extensions).